# How to change colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark, and so on by Firebase Remote Config?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

What I am trying to do is to save the colorPrimay, colorDarkPrimary and so on, values in RemoteConfig of Firebase so that I could able to change the colors of the apps from remote config and I did following

UPDATE:
What I am trying to do is to save the colorPrimay, colorDarkPrimary and so on, values in RemoteConfig of Firebase so that I could able to change the colors of the apps from remote confi. How could I do that?

UPDATE:

What I have tried is like

```
<--!remote_config_default.xml!-->


<defaultsMap>
<entry>
    <key>primaryColor</key>
    <value>#9c27b0</value>
</entry>
<entry>
    <key>colorPrimaryDark</key>
    <value>#7b1fa2</value>
</entry>
<entry>
    <key>colorAccent</key>
    <value>#FF4081</value>
</entry>
<entry>welcomeMessage</entry>
<value>Connection Failed</value>
```

And fetch like this

```
    void applyRemoteConfig() {
        mFirebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
        mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaults(R.xml.remote_config_default);
        // cacheExpirationSeconds is set to cacheExpiration here, indicating that any previously
// fetched and cached config would be considered expired because it would have been fetched
// more than cacheExpiration seconds ago. Thus the next fetch would go to the server unless
// throttling is in progress. The default expiration duration is 43200 (12 hours).
        int cacheExpiration = 1000;
        final String TAG = "Riddles";
        mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(cacheExpiration)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Fetch Succeeded");
                            // Once the config is successfully fetched it must be activated before newly fetched
                            // values are returned.
                            mFirebaseRemoteConfig.activateFetched();
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Fetch failed");
                            String message = mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getString("welcomeMessage");
                            displayWelcomeMessage(message);
                            Log.d(TAG, message);
                        }
                    }
                });

        String message = mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getString("welcomeMessage");
        displayWelcomeMessage(message);
        Log.d(TAG, message);


    }
```

But the

```
mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getString("colorPrimary");

mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getString("colorDarkPrimary");

mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getString("welcomeMessage");
```

Are returning Null.

Answer (score 2):

You could add this to your remote config file.

```
<!-- color entries -->
    <entry>
        <key>color_primary</key>
        <value>#3F51B5</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <key>color_primary_dark</key>
        <value>#303F9F</value>
    </entry>
```

To change your app's colour dynamically, have a flag supplied by remote config as well and change it using `fetch()`. For elaborate implementations [refer to this.](https://segunfamisa.com/posts/firebase-remote-config)

Comment: Yeah I have done that see the UPDATE what I have done

Comment: @NgimaSherpa is your fetch successful? Can u check the logger to see if fetch was successful?

Comment: it says Fetch failed

Comment: although it was failed to fatch it should get from default value right?

Comment: @NgimaSherpa where r u calling fetch() from?

Comment: from onCreate method of MainActivity

Comment: I also tried from onPostResume method but problem not solved